# Can't find a correct encoding to decode Chinese from Excel

Tags: python, excel, encoding

I am trying to decode the .csv file that has strange characters in it, but nothing seems to work. It is Chinese somehow encoded and it looks like *STä¸śćµ·A,ćµ·ĺŤ—ĺ¤§ä¸śćµ·ć—…ć. I tried a bunch o different encodings but they don't seem to work. Checked with chardet and it outputs it is 'UTF-8-SIG', but when I read this file to Python dataframe it still shows strange letters. Not sure where to look for solutions further or what to google even anymore.Thanks!

Comment: not sure about your character, better to post a picture. For Chinese charactor codes:GB2312、BIG5、GBK、GB18030、Unicode

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add original Chinese text along with corresponding garbled text (the latter as string as well as byte sequence if possible, please).

Comment: the problem is the garbled thing: (ć­¦äľŻć–°ĺźŽç®ˇĺ§”äĽšĺ†…) ć­¦ĺ…´äş  is the one i have, i don't have original Chinese, I want to decode this thing to get the original Chinese.